# Jmeter Common Error Handler for Thread Group

Tags: error-handling, jmeter

In Jmeter, within a threadgroup, I have a list of webservice request. Instead of handling the error for each request sepreately, can I have a common error handler for the threadgroup which on end of each iteration, will print out the required data for the failed request  (like servciename, jobid, error message). Each request has its assertion defined.

Or it is a better approach to handle and write the error output for each request seperately using postprocesser scripts.

Answer (score 2):

> Each request has its assertion defined

If the assertion logic is common for all the requests I would rather recommend using a single assertion for all the requests. JMeter Assertions obey [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/) so you will be able to apply pass/fail criteria to all requests in a single shot.

Your current setup violates [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle by making your test plan bigger and less suitable for refactoring, if you have only one assertion and need to change something - you will need to change something at one place only, if you have an assertion per request - you will have to visit each and every request

Answer (score 1):

Assertion is a good way to look for error scenarios. To make error handling generic, you can take advantage of fact that if you add an assertion (or any of the pre/post processors, timers) at thread group level or at a specific controller, it will execute after every sampler is completed

> Assertions are used to perform additional checks on samplers, and are
> processed after every sampler in the same scope. To ensure that an
> Assertion is applied only to a particular sampler, add it as a child
> of the sampler.

More details [here](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [JSR223 Post Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) to for the response status checking and printing the required fields.

```
if(vars.get("JMeterThread.last_sample_ok").toBoolean()){

    log.info("Request: ${prev.getSampleLabel()} Service Name : ${prev.getUrlAsString()}  JobId: ${vars.get('jobid')} Error : ${prev.getResponseMessage()}")
    
}
```

You can modify the script to suite your need.

[image]